# Variable not being passed

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is working. It asks for an http link and then passes it along to the Vlc Video Player.  Now I'm trying to make it look nicer and add a form box where again the http link will be inputted and then the input variable I'm now calling $X will be passed to the Vlc video player.  Something is wrong with the code on the new script and the Vlc player is not opening.  Could anyone help me?  Thanks

Working Script

```
$link = read-host "Enter your Http Link" 
$ip = read-host "Enter your Local Ip Address:Port "
$processArgs = "$link",":sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,ab=128,
channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/stream} :sout-all :sout-keep"
start-process "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" $processArgs    
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"    
"https://dabble.me/cast/?video_link=http://$ip/stream"
```

Non Working Script

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
{$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
{$objForm.Close()}})
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Enter the Http Link:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

**$x** 

$ip = read-host "Enter your Local Ip Address:Port "
$processArgs = "$x",":sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,
ab=128,channels=2, samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/stream} 
:sout-all :sout-keep"
start-process "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" $processArgs  
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"     
"https://dabble.me/cast/?video_link=http://$ip/stream"
```

Comment: At a very minimum, you need to specify what programming language you're using. Also, this is enough code that a SSCCE would be helpful; see http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Sorry, this is a Powershell script.

Comment: Updated tagging appropriately. It still would be helpful to generate a more minimal reproducer; surely you don't need the text boxes, labels and such to recreate the problem.

Comment: http://www.sapien.com/software/communitytools#PrimalFormsCE ... @Charles he clearly does need the text boxes if hes not coding them right

Comment: @Cole9350 ...but if he *does* need the text boxes (or, rather, **one** text box), then he *doesn't* need the VLC call. It's a problem retrieving the data with the UI, _or_ a problem doing something with it after, and figuring out which to generate a more minimal reproducer would solve (at least half) the problem.

Comment: Your "thank you" answer was deleted because Stack Overflow has a Q&A format, not a thread format. "Answer" means you're answering the question; it's not like "Reply" in a discussion forum. If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment or answer thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix:**

```
Try replacing $x with $Script:x everywhere in your script
```

**Explanation:**

You are assuming the $x you have in the script block is accessible from outside. It's not. One way you can overcome this is using $script:VariableName approach. The variables you defined that way will visible to all code blocks within that script